# Convert date MySQL

Tags: sql, qliksense

I need help to convert a date/time field on a database to a normal format. It is displayed like this: 01DEC2021:08:13:01

How can I convert it to a normal DD/MM/YYYY and HH/MM in SQL (or Qlik)? I know I need to use the SLECT STR_TO_DATE, but can't find the exact paramethers.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say you're storing date+time values as text in your database?

Comment: The info is stored in a txt, which is converted into a table in a database, yes. I need to import that string as date and time into Qlik. I don't have permissions to edit the database, but as Qlik accepts SQL commands to import, I want to use STR_TO_DATE to do it while it charges the information.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT str_to_date("01DEC2021:08:13:01", "%d%b%Y:%H:%i:%S")`

It's written in the description under `STR_TO_DATE` on how to parse each token; see here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Comment: Thanks!! That worked, but only for that example. How could I do it massively for all the dates/times in the table? :(

Comment: Just replace the fixed string with the name of the cell / attribute if the format is the same everywhere